# How to add custom formatting in prettier (or es-lint)

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have a script in my React JS project that allows to reorder imports in three specific categories:

1. Imports from dependencies libraries
2. Imports from internal components
3. Imports from styles files

All works well, using the command `npm run order-imports`

Now, I'm interested to run this script directly in VS Code, for example when I'm writing code, I want to do Crt+S and run this script to reorder my imports.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.json, either for your workspace or vscode global,

add this

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true, // This will organize all your imports 
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true // if  you want to fix other fixable inting errors
     },
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, It is not exactly that I want.